# create usercontrol using javascript or winJS or angularJS for Windows8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-8, windows-8.1, winjs

I am developing a windows 8.1 application using html5/javascript. Need to create usercontrols like we create in native windows application.
Reason:Single page has code of multiple pages/modules, so for code cleanup and better understanding.

How to create usercontrols or is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is possibility to do the same. WinJS has [fragments](http://try.buildwinjs.com/#fragments) that you can load and unload, in same manner as usercontrols in windows forms. Also pages behave in same way, if you are using the Windows JavaScript template application "navigator.js"-file.

[Here is image from MSDN site how navigator.js switches pages into default.html](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC591337.png)

Example:

In the main HTML file define button which loads the fragment for testing purpose and div with id where the fragment will be loaded:

```
<div class="box">
    <button class="win-button action" id="basicFragmentLoadButton">Load the fragment</button><br />
    <div id="basicFragmentLoadDiv"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="status"></div>
</div>
```

In Javascript file utilize WinJS.UI.Fragments namespace "renderCopy" function to render the content of the html file you want to use as usercontrol:

```
// Assign element into variable
var basicFragmentLoadDiv = document.querySelector("#basicFragmentLoadDiv");

function resetOutput() {
    basicFragmentLoadDiv.innerHTML = "";
}

function basicFragmentLoad() {
    resetOutput();


    WinJS.UI.Fragments.renderCopy("/pages/fragments/content/BasicFragmentLoad.html", basicFragmentLoadDiv)
        .done(
            function () {
                log("successfully loaded fragment", "sample", "status");
            },
            function (error) {
                log("error loading fragment: " + error, "sample", "error");
            }
        );
```

/pages/fragments/content/BasicFragmentLoad.html includes simply HTML elements that will be rendered into the main HTML file. You can find more in the fragments section in try.buildwinjs.com

Comment: can you please share any example for the same.

Comment: I added an example up for you.